# Removing duplicate values from one text file and count no of duplicate values

Tags: perl

I have two text files which is the output of perl script. The first textfile contains values like

```
1200 1215 1230 1245 1300 1315 1330 1345 1400
```

and the second textfile contains values like

```
1200 1200 1200 1215 1215 1230 1230 1230 1245 1245 1245 1300 1300 1300 1315 1315 1315 1330 1330 1345 1345 1400 1400 1400.
```

I want to remove the duplicates from textfile2 and compare it with the textfile1 and display the mismatch values and no of duplicate values in textfile2. Eg: I want to display "the no.of 1200 in textfile2 is 3, no of 1215 values is 2..etc. How to write perl code for this?

Comment: I have just directly compare the two text files but i donno how to elimanate the duplicates from textfile

Comment: post up your code so that we can help you...

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$\="\n";

open my $fh1, '<', 'textfile1.txt' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'textfile2.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

chomp(my @arr1=<$fh1>);
chomp(my @arr2=<$fh2>);

foreach my $x (@arr1){
        print $out $x if (!grep (/^\Q$x\E$/,@arr2));
}

close $fh1;
close $fh2;
close $out;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach my $x (@arr1){
    my $cnt;
    print $out "no of $x is $cnt" if $cnt = grep (/$x/,@arr2);
}
```

---

this is edited your code from comment.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
$\="\n";
open my $fh1, '<', 'textfile1.txt' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'textfile2.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;
chomp(my @arr1=<$fh1>);
chomp(my @arr2=<$fh2>);

foreach my $x (@arr1){
    my $cnt;
    print $out "no of $x is $cnt" if $cnt = grep (/$x/,@arr2);
}
close $fh1;
close $fh2;
close $out
```

---

only array test code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @arr1=(1200, 1215, 1230, 1245, 1300, 1315, 1330, 1345, 1400);
my @arr2=(1200, 1200, 1200, 1215, 1215, 1230, 1230, 1230, 1245, 1245, 1245, 1300, 1300, 1300, 1315, 1315, 1315, 1330, 1330, 1345, 1345, 1400, 1400, 1400);

foreach my $x (@arr1){
    my $cnt;
    print "no of $x is $cnt\n" if $cnt = grep (/$x/,@arr2);
}
```

Comment: @Dora Work flawlessly Where I tried this. you tried to check the contents of the array?

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl

my @array1=`cat /home/xdorjos/resultfile.txt`;
my @array2=`cat /home/xdorjos/statsrop.txt`;
foreach my $x (@array1){
    my $cnt;
    print $out "no of $x is $cnt" if $cnt = grep (/$x/,@array2);
}

Comment: But i got message like this "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./gpeh.pl line 8." after executing the script

Comment: can u pls paste the code here.. im not able to access that sample link which u sent juz nw

Comment: `undefined value` `$out`

Answer (score -2):

Are you set on using Perl?  If not, this is very easy to do in excel.